# List Nodes/Content Type Items with same tags as current

Tags: taxonomy-terms

On the node page I'd like to add a linked list of other nodes tagged with the same tag/taxonomy term. How can this be achieved? Via Views?

Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a module that does that for you: [Similar by Terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms). But you can also do this with Views using Contextual Filters & Relationships. [This comment](http://drupal.org/node/65375#comment-4264226) on Drupal.org explains it quite well:

> Its really easy in D7. Coding is not at all required.
>
> Taxonomy is a field in D7. I will explain how to create a Related
>   Content block using Views.
>
> Create an argument by adding the taxonomy field on which you want to
>   find the related nodes. Select "Provide default argument". Argument
>   type = "Taxonomy Term ID from URL" Remove tick from "Load default
>   argument from term page" Tick the "Load default argument from node
>   page, thats good for related taxonomy blocks." To remove duplicates
>   you have to follow the following points.
>
> Open "Query settings" in the "Advanced Settings". Tick "Distinct".
>   This gives you a perfect "Related Articles" or "Related Nodes" using
>   Views.

Comment: Thanks Baysaa. I'm actually trying to do this programmatically. hmmm...

Comment: @DanielSachs then you can just copy the code you need from that module ^^. Or use it as a guide. I'm sure it'll be better as it should've gone through the issue logs, bug fixes, security reviews etc. No point in re-inventing the wheel I always say. That's what Open Source is about.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, a bit frustrating due to lack of documentation and me being relatively new to Drupal.
So here we go:

```
#Let's find out what term is used
$my_node_tag = $node->field_your_field_used_in_node['und'][0]['tid'];

#Get the array of nodes IDs
$nodeid = taxonomy_select_nodes($my_node_tag, FALSE);  

#And here we go
$counter = 0;
foreach($nodeid as $nid) {
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $alias = drupal_get_path_alias("node/$nid");
    print '<div class="title"><a href="' . base_path() . $alias.'">';
    print $node->title;
    print '</a></div>';
    $counter++;
}
```

Lovely. Not sure how efficient this is, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not really needed to install other module when we can achieve this using core ones [see this tuto](http://scito.ch/content/show-related-nodes-block-based-taxonomy-terms-views-3-and-drupal-7) to fond out how.